# Create an action in Photoshop using multiple photos and eye dropper tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions

In the latest version of Adobe Photoshop, can one create an action where it opens multiple photos and then takes a color sample using the eye dropper tool to select from a specific area of each photo and then saves that color sample as a separate jpg file?

Comment: Hello and welcome to GDSE. opening specific photos and picking specific area are totally out of boundaries of ACTIONS because your action will work perfectly for that  specific image only and if you change images then there are chances that actions will be failed. I'll suggest to go with scripts rather than actions :D

Comment: Mr. Online is right, that'd be only possible with script, but rather a simple one. How that specific area is defined? What's the sample doc size?

Comment: How would your script / action know where in the photo to use the eye dropper?